# Need help resolving c# DataContract deserializing error

Tags: c#

I am trying to deserialze an XML document to a c# DataContract and encountering errors:

The error message is as:

> Error in line 2 position 2. Expecting element 'Ernmxml' from namespace
>   'http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32'.. Encountered 'Element'  with
>   name 'NewReleaseMessage', namespace
>   'http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32'

I haven't completed the entire DataContract as yet but here is what I have so far:

```
namespace DdexCoverter
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Ernmxml
    {

        [IgnoreDataMemberAttribute] public string NewReleaseMessage;
        [DataMember] public string PartId;

    }
}
```

Here is my Main program:

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileStream xmlstream = File.OpenRead(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xmlfilepath"]);
            var xr = new XmlTextReader(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xmlfilepath"]);

            var ddexxml =  new Ernmxml();

            var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Ernmxml));

            var ernmobj = (Ernmxml) dcs.ReadObject(xr);



        }
    }
}
```

The error is generated at this line:
var ernmobj = (Ernmxml) dcs.ReadObject(xr);

The XML beginning looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ern:NewReleaseMessage xmlns:ern="http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32"
                       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                       LanguageAndScriptCode="en"
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32 http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32/ern-main.xsd"
                       MessageSchemaVersionId="2010/ern-main/32">
  <MessageHeader>
    <MessageThreadId>PADPIDA</MessageThreadId>
    <MessageId>PADPIDA</MessageId>
    <MessageSender>
      <PartyId>PADPIDA</PartyId>
      <PartyName>
```

Can someone please advice me how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 public class Ernmxml
```

to

```
public class NewReleaseMessage
```

or

Change

```
<ern:NewReleaseMessage xmlns:ern="http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32"
```

or

```
<ern:Ernmxml xmlns:ern="http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DataMember is defined as just a public field.  DataMember and XmlSerializer work only with public properties.  Your object model must also match the object model of the XML.  If I reverse engineeered it correctly, this is what you should be getting:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class MessageHeader
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string MessageThreadId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string MessageId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public MessageSender sender { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class MessageSender
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string PartyId { get; set; }
    }
```

I usually start with a class definition then serialize the object to see how the format looks.  Not accustomed to reverse engineering xml.  :)

This should then be placed inside your NewReleaseMessage class as just

```
    MessageHeader message {get;set;}
```

Another thing I just noticed is your use of the DataContractSerializer.  Just do this:

```
    using ( FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(pathToFile))
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NewReleaseMessage));
        NewRealeaseMessage data = ser.Deserialize(stream) as NewReleaseMessage;
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this and got: {"<NewReleaseMessage xmlns='http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32'> was not expected."}

Comment: Oops, sorry.  You need to add a wrapping class of NewReleaseMessage for it to work.